# OroCRM: New user role doesnt have VIEW access

Tags: symfony, orocrm

I created new role in “User Management/Roles”
I’ve set full access to Opportunities entity for this role (System)
The other entities permissions are set to “None”

Now users with this role can create opportunities. But cannot view them (red alert “You do not have permission to perform this action”)
I think, that new role needs to grant more permissions for some entities…

Comment: Not sure it's a question, try orocrm forum :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update oro entity cache after adding acl annotations to entity.
app/console 'oro:entity-config:update --force' solved my problem